# Launching character in the direction of the mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've asked this same question before but since then I've updated my code to take their advice into consideration, but it still doesn't work. This time I will post the full code. Please keep in mind that I am still a beginner in unity and the code might not look good compared to what your used to.

edit: im sorry one of the tags says Unity3d rather than 2d, this is 2d and i don't know why but it keeps on changing the tag to unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class playermovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public static System.Diagnostics.TraceListenerCollection Listeners { get; }
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Camera cam;
    public float shootRange = 5f;
    Vector2 movement;    
    Vector2 mousePos;
    Vector2 lookDir;
    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 180;
        rb.rotation = angle;
    
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("huzza!");
        mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("huzza!");
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * shootRange);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: If you are making a 2d game, use `transform.right`, not `transform.forward`. The rotation code looks rather standard to aim in a specific direction. I had commented on your last question to use `transform.forward` as I assumed you were making a 3d game. I now see you were using `Vector2` for storing variables - that's my bad.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is get the shoot direction. Which in both 2D and 3D is the direction you want to move towards minus the current position.

```
direction = target - current
```

Now you just need to get the actual positions of both your player object and the mouse translated to the world position.
In 3D getting the mouse to world position this is actually easier, but in 2D you will need take the Z property into account and compensate for that.

Luckily this bit of code is well known and you can just copy and paste to get the mouse to world positon:

```
Vector3 GetScreenToWorld()
{
    Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePos.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane;
    var worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
    return worldPosition;
}
```

Now you need to calculate the direction the player needs to move in

```
void LaunchPlayer () {
    
    var dir = GetScreenToWorld() - transform.position;
    dir = dir.normalized;
    ...
}
```

We calculate the direction then normalize it to remove the magnitude. Otherwise the player will get pushed harder or softer depending on how far away it is.
The next step is then to simply add the force in the direction you want.

```
void LaunchPlayer () {
    
    var dir = GetScreenToWorld() - transform.position;
    dir = dir.normalized;
    
    // Add the force to the RB
    rb.AddForce(transform.forward * shootRange);
}
```

Below is the complete solution:

```
public float moveSpeed = 5f;
public static System.Diagnostics.TraceListenerCollection Listeners { get; }
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public Camera cam;
public float shootRange = 5f;
Vector2 movement;    
Vector2 mousePos;
Vector2 lookDir;

void Start () 
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    
    // Launch the player
    /*
        Button click events should be the Update() or 
        LateUpdate() function to avoid jittery controls
    */
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        LaunchPlayer ();
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Move the player
    MovePlayer();

    // Rotate the player
    RotatePlayer();
}

void MovePlayer() 
{
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}

void RotatePlayer()
{
    lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 180;
    rb.rotation = angle;
}

void LaunchPlayer () {
    
    var dir = GetScreenToWorld() - transform.position;
    dir = dir.normalized;
    
    // Add the force to the RB
    rb.AddForce(transform.forward * shootRange);
} 

Vector3 GetScreenToWorld()
{
    Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePos.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane;
    var worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
    return worldPosition;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but unfortunately it didn't work. I might have implemented this wrong but it says that the lookDir isn't defined and its returning to the default value (the middle of the screen) and now the character will only look at the middle of the screen. And clicking does not launch the player.

This is probably a problem on my part but I don't know what could be causing it so if you have any idea could you please tell me?

Comment: Sorry add the following line to the Rotate() function. At the top of it `Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;`, if it still doesn't work change `lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;` to `var lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;`

Comment: Sorry i was so late to reply, i was pretty preoccupied. This still didn't fix the code, well at least it has a different error "Operator '-' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector2'. And i don't see how this could fix the player not shooting, it might be a problem with my implementing the code though. if you have any idea could you please tell me?